# Add to tail of lock-less list

Tags: linux, algorithm, linked-list, linux-kernel, lockless

I'm using the Linux kernel's lock-less list as defined in `llist.h`.  `llist_add` adds to the list, but it adds the new node right after the head.  How can I add to the tail of the list in constant time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add to the tail of the list in constant time?

You cannot.

Lockless property for `llist`'s comes at the cost of reduced functionality: only addition to the beginning, removing the first element and removing all elements are supported. And even this reduction is not sufficient for make it lockless *always*, see description at the beginning of the header [inclide/linux/llist.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/llist.h#L178).

Actually, lockless property of some objects is *rarely a requirement*. In most cases usage of spinlocks is acceptible. If it is your case, instead of lockfree `llist` you may use double-linked lists `list_head`, protected by spinlocks. Double-linked lists stores pointer to the last element and supports addition after it (function `list_add_tail`).

Comment: We are currently using spinlocks with ```list_head``` but were looking for ways to eliminate/reduce the lock.

Comment: Perhaps RCU can help?